# How to insert data with select from a different context in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have two SQLite files and I use Entity Framework Core to handle the data.

Basically, I have two contexts that has the *same database structure*.

```
SourceDatabaseContext sourceDatabaseContext = new SourceDatabaseContext(file1);
TargetDatabaseContext targetDatabaseContext = new TargetDatabaseContext(file2);
```

I need to copy a large amount of data from one file to the other (the target already contains data so I can't overwrite it), but I try to avoid using entity objects.

I know that I can execute SQL commands with the contexts' `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` method but I don't know how to connect the two contexts.

This is what I'd like to achieve:

```
targetDatabaseContext.Database.ExecuteSQLCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM sourceDatabase.Table1");
```

I guess this is like a *cross-context SQL command usage*, but I'm not sure if it can be done or there could be an alternative solution.

What should I do about this problem?

**UPDATE**

I add some methods to show how the Entity Framework saving is currently done.

```
public async Task Start()
{
  try
  {
    SetBulkOperations(true);
    await StartTransaction();
    await SaveAllEntities();
    CommitTransaction();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    RollbackTransaction();
  }
  finally
  {
    SetBulkOperations(false);  
  }
}



public async Task StartTransaction() => await context.Database?.BeginTransactionAsync();

public void SetBulkOperations(bool isOn) => context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = !isOn;

public void CommitTransaction() => context.Database?.CurrentTransaction?.Commit();

public void RollbackTransaction() => context.Database?.CurrentTransaction?.Rollback();

public async Task SaveAllEntities()
{
  var logItems = await repository2.GetLogItems();
  if(logItems.Count > 0)
    await SaveListAsync(logItems, true);
  //...and it goes on   
}


public async Task SaveListAsync<TType>(List<TType> data, bool isNew) where TType : class
{
  if (isNew)  
    await context.Set<TType>().AddRangeAsync(data);
 await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: just copy sqlite file?

Comment: @vasily.sib I updated the initial post, check it again please.

Comment: There is no such thing as _"cross-context SQL command"_. But why do you try to avoid using entity objects? This is a key of any ORM. If you realy need to avoid it, why don't you use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`?

Comment: I try to avoid because the insert is so slow that it takes 3 minutes to insert a few thousand objects. If I do it with an SQLite transaction, I hope for a much quicker execution.

Comment: What's wrong with [EF transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)?

Comment: Using Entity Framework transactions, it took 2 minutes to save a few thousand entities (without transaction, it took about 4 minutes). Using SQLite transactions, it takes _2-3 seconds_ even when there is double amount of data.

Comment: looks like you doing it wrong :\ Can you show us your code where you insert this records?

Comment: I updated the initial post.

Comment: Try to move `await context.SaveChangesAsync()` out of the loop, i.e. to the `CommitTransaction` method

Comment: Creating an _explicit_ transaction doesn't make the `SaveChanges` calls wait for the commit to happen and no save is made until then? This is what is the different between the implicit and explicit transactions in Entity Framework, right? Like in this article, where multiple `SaveChanges` is called: http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2016/09/21/implicit-and-explicit-transactions-in-entity-framework/

Comment: I just create a dummy .net console project to test it. I'm adding 10 000 simple records in 1.8 second, are your `LogItem` too large?

Comment: also, your link is talking about EF6, but you are on EF Core, don't you?

Comment: Yes, my entities are quite large (about 10-30 properties), and yes, I use Entity Framework Core. Does it behave differently regarding explicit transactions?

Comment: by large I mean _"have a large property like byte[1024 * 1024 * 10]"_, objects with 10-30 normal string or decimal or datetime properties are still small objects

Comment: Then they are not that large :) I add an _interim_ solution to this question as I have a deadline to make and I needed an alternative but I'm open to suggestions to optimize the Entity Framework Core part of the software.

Comment: can you try to rewrite your code to be more like in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Saving/Saving/Transactions/ControllingTransaction/Sample.cs) I think that `context.Database?.CurrentTransaction?` may be defferent from that one returned by `await context.Database?.BeginTransactionAsync()`. There is also no use for `ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` - you may omit it.